# Keeping track of mapped values of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, mapping

So I had a large matrix(4091252x2) with large values like this:

```
 439105     1053224
  439105     1696241
  439105      580064
  439105     1464748
 1836139     1593258
 1464748      439105
 1464748     1053224
 1464748     1696241
 1464748      580064
  580064      439105
```

that I mapped down to smaller numbers. However, how would I keep track of the numbers that I mapped?

For example, assuming that I have a matrix like

```
A = [110  503 
     402  110
     300  900
     300  402]
```

and mapped it to:

```
B = [1  4 
     3  1
     2  5 
     2  3]
```

using:

```
[~,~,D] = unique(A);
B = reshape(D,size(A))
```

How could I write a function to keep track of the values that I mapped? For example that 110 = 1? I'm just not sure how to approach the problem, and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It maps in order so first output

```
[largeMap,~,D] = unique(A);
B = reshape(D,size(A)) ;
smallMap = (1:length(largeMap))';
map = [largeMap, smallMap];
```

Comment: Thanks, I played around with that code, and it works!!